# Error with transfering MySQL database (connected via PDO) from localhost to hosted server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, localhost

Okay, so this is my code:

```
try {
$pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name','user','password'); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
exit ('Database error.');
}
```

I tried so many different combinations with host name, username and password, and every time I get 'Database error'.

My question is: 
What should I do to succesfully transfer MySQL database from localhost to my hosted server using this part of code (which is my connection.php file)?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: never output a fixed error string, especially when developing, if you had `exit($e->getMessage())` you'd at least get some USEFUL information about why the connection failed.

Comment: That fully depends on the host's configuration.

Comment: I know that depends on the host's configuration, and I tried with IP address of server, and my username of it, and password that I'm using to log in CPanel, but nothing. Then I tried with PHPMyAdmin log in details (username and password), and nothing.

Comment: Who is your host? Several, if not all hosts do not use the hosting itself as the connection address, but a different server altogether.

Comment: InterWorx.

@MarcB I took your advice and now I have this: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'aleksandarpajic'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Then I suggest you look through their FAQ/Support section as to which server config to use.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this try catch stuff. Leave it as

```
 $pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name','user','password');
```

And see what it says (on-screen or logs)

Answer (score -1):

Use this try and catch block for error trace

```
try {

        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name','user','password');
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I'm getting an error that says:  SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'aleksandarpajic'@'localhost' (using password: NO) .
What does that mean?